I have a problem with notifications appearing twice on filament 3
I'm using filament 3 with laravel 10, so the problem is when I use after() after adding data entry there are 2 notifications that appear, the first is the default notification then the notification that I created, how do I solve this?
Layout livewire
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
 
        <meta name="application-name" content="{{ config('app.name') }}">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
        <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
 
        <style>
            [x-cloak] {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
 
        @filamentStyles
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    </head>
 
    <body class="antialiased">
        {{ $slot }}
 
        @livewire('notifications')
 
        @filamentScripts
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
    </body>
</html>

class component TableList.php

<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Pages;

use App\Models\Movie;
use App\Services\MovieSchema;
use Filament\Forms\Concerns\InteractsWithForms;
use Filament\Tables\Concerns\InteractsWithTable;
use Filament\Forms\Contracts\HasForms;
use Filament\Tables\Contracts\HasTable;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Livewire\Component;

class TableList extends Component implements HasTable, HasForms
{

    use InteractsWithTable, InteractsWithForms;

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->query(Movie::query())
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('title')->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('category.name'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('director'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('release')->date()->sortable(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
                    ->form(MovieSchema::schema()),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make()->action(function (Movie $movie) {
                    $movie->delete();
                    Notification::make()
                        ->title("Hapus Berhasil : {$movie->title}")
                        ->success()
                        ->send();
                })
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()->model(Movie::class)
                    ->modal()
                    ->form(MovieSchema::schema())
                    ->after(function () {
                        Notification::make()
                            ->title("Tambah Berhasil")
                            ->success()
                            ->send();
                    })
            ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pages.table-list');
    }

}

I hope the notification that appears is only 1 that I created, the default one I can turn off, I tried to find an article and was advised to use ->disableNotifications() but it doesn't work for me.

Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()->model(Movie::class)
                ->modal()
                ->form(MovieSchema::schema())
                ->after(function () {
                    Notification::make()
                        ->title("Tambah Berhasil")
                        ->success()
                        ->send();
                })->successNotification(null)

Try this
->successNotification(null)

it's working for me.
